# xcode builds the project with iOS 10 device but crashes when launching: Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm trying to build and run the iOS app with Xcode7 and iOS10 iPhone5s. It builds succeeds, but it crashes when launching. It has no problem when running with iOS9 or earlier. Please help me to detect what makes my app crush when iOS10.

what I tried:

- set breakpoint in AppDelegate.
  the program goes to  init() methods, but it doesn't reach application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions or application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions. I have no idea about which methods the program goes to after init().
- use Instrument
  It's wired that it succeeds to launch the app when using Instrument, so I can't detect which process leak memory with Instrument.
- checking CPU
  [image]

What I haven't tried:

- delete one pod and build for every pod:
  it takes much time, that's why I haven't tried.

Comment: also i tried to  set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug, but nothing is shown

Answer (score 0):

I think I have same problem. Though I'm using xcode 8.0 that contains iOS 10 sdk. I don't think you can build iOS 10 devices from xcode 7, I could be wrong though.

You could try downloading xcode 8 
https://developer.apple.com/download/
also quick fix might be changing deployment target higher if it's really small like 6 or 7.

I hope this fix your problem. It's frustrating since the crash seems to happen before application code actually is started to process.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution for now. 
If I run the project with simulator with iOS10, `Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both...`
Then I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532396/5341236